# How to make Babel handle LESS files?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, less, babeljs

I have an isomorphic React app with server side rendering setup with NodeJS. I'm using Babel and Webpack, which work pretty fine except one problem:

> Babel can't handle `require('somefile.less')`.

For this reason I'm using Webpack to compile both backend and frontend code since Webpack has nice CSS and LESS loaders and it doesn't freak out on seeing CSS or LESS files. However, this approach comes with its own problem:

> Server start time increases a lot, since webpack has to compile entire
>   backend first.

This is fine when I'm deploying code for production, but in development environment, it's really hurting productivity.

`babel-node` utility, on the other hand, is super fast in comparison, if only I can make it handle CSS/LESS files. Hence my question: can we make Babel work with CSS/LESS files?

Comment: I believe you need Webpack in order to even be able to use `require`. You need a module environment like the ones provided by Webpack, Browserify or Node in order to load modules. Babel is just a transpiler, it doesn't handle that part by itself.

Comment: @PedroCastilho You're right, we need webpack even to be able to use `require` at frontend. But here, my question is around backend transpilation.

Comment: Do you mean for something like server-side rendering?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with "requiring" LESS files at backend (server side rendering).

Comment: You can use Gulp or some other build system to compile Less to CSS, and use [Juice](https://github.com/Automattic/juice) to inline the compiled CSS into your HTML. The whole pipeline could be automated using Gulp.

Answer (score 0):

[Babel is a JavaScript compiler](https://babeljs.io/docs/en)

Babel is a toolchain that is mainly used to convert ECMAScript 2015+ code into a backwards compatible version of JavaScript in old browsers or environments.

So the answer is **no**. Babel works only with JS files.